# Upload remote file using AJAX to other server

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a requirement where a web page will be populated with a list of URLs to files and a button (Transfer files) for the user to click on by a PHP script. When user clicks on 'Transfer Files' , all the files need to be uploaded to a second server. The second server supports JSON type form submits.

Is this possible to do with JQuery AJAX?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: "The second server supports JSON type form submits"
So there is a REST web service, what is it expecting in that JSON?  The file URLs?  The file contents plus other data like file name, description?
Depending on the answers, then yes it should be possible for script code to fetch files (if needed) from server 1 and send their contents or locations to server 2 using the web service.

Comment: Hi @Dave s, thanks for you comment. Yes the API is rest like but not truely REST. The API expects the file content. Should i download the files from server 1 first and the upload to server 2? I am able to upload by manually attaching files to html forms. I just want to the attaching part to be done from the code. Thanks

Comment: For client-side script running in a browser I think you'll need to fetch from server 1 using AJAX, keep in memory not write to a file, then send from memory to server 2 using AJAX.  This assumes you're right about server 2 accepting JSON and not expecting form-multipart.